# Help with Cantor Bernstein Theorem proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Suppose $X,Y$ are sets such that $ \left| X \right| \leq  \left| Y \right|, \left| Y \right| \leq  \left| X \right|.$ Then $\left| X \right| =  \left| Y \right| $

Proof:
Let $f:X \to Y, g:Y \to X$ be injective functions. Then, $\left| X \right| = \left| g[f[X]] \right|$ and $\left| Y \right| = \left| g[f[Y]] \right|$ Let $A=X, B=g[Y]$ and it suffices to prove $\left| A \right| = \left|B \right|$

Consider $F:\mathcal P \left({A}\right)\ \to \mathcal P \left({A}\right) $ be defined by $ F(X) = (A-B) \cup g[f[X]] $. Then $F$ is monotone and $\exists C\in \mathcal P \left({A}\right)\ $ such that $C=(A-B)\cup g[f[C]]$

Define  $h: A \to B$ by $$
h(x) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&g(f(x)) &&, x\in C =(A-B)\cup g[f[C]]\\
&x &&, x\in A-C
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

Suppose $h[C] \cap h[A-C] \neq  \emptyset $. Then, $ \exists x [x \in A-C \wedge x\in  C$ ](Contradiction).

Since $h\restriction_{A-C}$ and $h\restriction_C$ are injective,  it follows that $h$ is injective.

Clearly, $h[A] \subseteq B$. Let $b \in B = g[Y]$. Then, $b\in A-C \lor b\in C$. 
If $b\in A-C,$ then $ b\in h[A-C],$ by definition of $h$. 
If $b\in C$, then $b \in g[f[C]]$, i.e. $ \exists c\in C: b = f(g(c))  $ and  hence $b\in h[C] $. So $h$ is surjective.

Is my proof valid? Thank you.

Comment: Why does it suffice to prove $|A|=|B|$?

Comment: Why indeed does it suffice to prove |A| = |B| ? With A and B as defined it would suffice to prove that A = B, i.e. that g(Y) = X so that g would then be a bijection, but this is not implied by |A| = |B|. For example |even natural numbers| is famously proved equal to |natural numbers| but the sets are not the same. Furthermore, you are not going to be able to prove that g is a bijection, because in general it's not true. Last point: you presumably mean to refer to f(g(Y)) not g(f(Y).

Comment: Your approach to the proof if done correctly is a combination of the Tarski fixed point theorem and Banach decomposition theorem. In outline - The function F is actually defined as F(S: S ⊂ A) = A\g[B\f(S)]. F is shown to be monotone. Tarski says a monotone function has a fixed point, say D where D = F(D). Banach uses this to show that you can use F to partition A and B {A1, A2}  {B1, B2} such that B1 = f(A1) and A2 = g(B2). The proof is completed by establishing that g has an inverse g` so that B2 = g`(A2).

Answer (score 0):

I think the proof is valid, with the caveat mentioned about f(g(Y)).

Note that Banach's partitioning theorem is from 1924 while the [Tarski(-Knaster) fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem) is from 1927. cf. my book
Arie Hinkis: *Proofs of the Cantor-Bernstein Theorem*, https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-0224-6